# Presto Value cannot be cast as TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, timestamp, presto

I'm getting the error, `value cannot be cast as timestamp: 2021-03-14 02:21:16`. This seems like a perfectly eligible candidate for a timestamp cast. Is there any reason why this error should be triggered?

I'm tempted to just use `TRY_CAST` and filter out the `NULL` values in a `WHERE` clause. But I'm not sure how prevalent this issue is and would like to better understand what's causing it. The type of the value in the db table is VARCHAR.

Comment: `select cast('2021-03-14 02:21:16' as timestamp)` works for me. How do you cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Presto has a bug where timestamps are not properly treated according to standard SQL behavior. What you're probably observing is a timestamp that falls in the daylight savings transition "gap" for the timezone of your session.

This issue is fixed in [Trino](https://trino.io) ([formerly known as Presto SQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)):

```
trino> select cast('2021-03-14 02:21:16' as timestamp);

          _col0
-------------------------
 2021-03-14 02:21:16.000
(1 row)
```